# Problemas con copiar un array dentro de otro array dinamico

Tags: c++, array, punteros

Tengo un problema con la ejecución de este programa. No sé porque razón termina ejecutándose tan bruscamente("El programa dejó de funcionar"). Los resultados del mismo son los que espero, sin embargo ocurre eso. Y traté muchas cosas para evitarlo y encontré que lo que provoca el error es la función `void IntArr::addElement(int qtty,int *vec);` ya que si la quito, el programa termina perfectamente y sin ningún error. Analice la función y para mí está bien, no sé que es lo que se me está escapando de las manos.
La función esa lo que debe hacer es pasar un array con la cantidad de elementos que quiero del mismo y agregarlos a otro array.

PD: el programa original estaba bien dividido por archivos(clase.h,clase.cpp,main.cpp), nada más que para copiarlos acá tuve que pegar todo junto.

Les agradecería mucho su ayuda. Saludos!

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
#define PRESS_KEY std::cout<<"\nPresione Enter para continuar . . .\n";std::cin.get();

class IntArr{
  private:
    int * p;
    int size;
    int used;
    //Verificador
    void redimensionador(int cant);

  public:
    //Constructores
    IntArr (int sz);
    IntArr (int sz,int qtty,int *vec);
    //Destructor
    ~IntArr();
    //Visualizadores
    void prtArr (void) const;
    void prtArr (int cant);
    //Accesores
    int getSize(){return size;};
    int getUsed(){return used;};
    //Operaciones
    void addElement(int xx);
    void addElement(int qtty,int *vec);
};
//Constructores
IntArr::IntArr(int sz){
  size = sz;
  used = 0;
  p = new int[size];
}
IntArr::IntArr(int sz,int qtty,int* vec){
  if(qtty>sz){
    sz = qtty;
  }
  size = sz;
  used = qtty;
  p = new int[size];
  p = vec;
}

//Destructor
IntArr::~IntArr(){
  delete []p;
}

//Visualizadores
void IntArr::prtArr(void) const{
  if(used == 0){
    cout<<endl<<"El array no tiene elementos."<<endl;
  }
  else{
    cout<<endl<<"Array: ";
    for(int i=0;i<used;i++){
      cout<<p[i]<<", ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
  }
}
void IntArr::prtArr(int cant){
  if(used == 0){
    cout<<endl<<"El array no tiene elementos."<<endl;
  }
  else{
    cout<<endl<<"Array: ";
    for(int i=0;i<cant;i++){
      cout<<p[i]<<", ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
  }
}

//Operaciones
double IntArr::getAvg(){
  double acum = 0;
  for(int i=0;i<used;i++){
    acum += p[i];
  }
  return (acum/used);
}
void IntArr::addElement(int xx){
  redimensionador(1);
  p[used] = xx;
  used++;
}
void IntArr::addElement(int qtty,int *vec){
  int j=0;
  redimensionador(qtty);
  for(int i=used;i<(used+qtty);i++){
    p[i] = vec[j];
    j++;
  }
  used += qtty;
}

//Verificador
void IntArr::redimensionador(int cant){
  if(cant+used>size){
    if(cant > 5){
      size += cant;
    }
    else{
      size += 5 + cant;
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  int v_aux[]= {0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40};
  IntArr A(10,sizeof(v_aux)/sizeof(int),v_aux);
  cout<<" size:"<<A.getSize()<<endl<<" used:"<<A.getUsed()<<endl;
  A.prtArr();
  A.addElement(77);
  cout<<" size:"<<A.getSize()<<endl<<" used:"<<A.getUsed()<<endl;
  A.prtArr();
  A.addElement(11);
  cout<<" size:"<<A.getSize()<<endl<<" used:"<<A.getUsed()<<endl;
  A.prtArr();
  A.addElement(8,v_aux);
  cout<<" size:"<<A.getSize()<<endl<<" used:"<<A.getUsed()<<endl;
  A.prtArr();
  PRESS_KEY;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el programa hay dos problemas, que pueden ocasionar que el programa deje de funcionar, las dos están relacionadas con el manejo de memoria y punteros (Usar punteros te permite escribir en cualquier posición de memoria pero tienes que estar seguro que la memoria esta disponible):

En el constructor estas asignando el puntero de entrada al buffer interno, en vez hay que copiar el contenido

```
  IntArr::IntArr(int sz,int qtty,int* vec){
  if(qtty>sz){
    sz = qtty;
  }
  size = sz;
  used = qtty;
  p = new int[size];
  memcpy (p,vec,qtty*sizeof(int))
}
```

En la función redimensionar solo estas aumentando la varialbe size, aqui tambien debes aumentar el tamaño del buffer

```
void IntArr::redimensionador(int cant){
   if(cant+used>size){
   if(cant > 5){
     size += cant;
   }
   else{
     size += 5 + cant;
  }
  int * temp = new int [size];
  memcpy (temp,p,used*sizeof(int)); // se copia el contenido del buffer
  delete [] p;// se borra el buffer anterior
  p = temp; //se asigna el nuevo buffer
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah eso no lo sabía, muchas gracias y muy bien explicado!!!!